# How to set backgroundColor like gradient?

Tags: react-native

I just can set basic color which is static, doesnt change.

Also how can I do the `borderRadius` part, since i made two different `View`'s.

On here, i just use this code for the color

```
  <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: "#3DB4EE" }}>
```

Here is how my app looks:

[image]

And here is how i want it to be seen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible without adding library and there for you have to use https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient

For border radius of white background you have to use style property `borderTopLeftRadius` and `borderTopRightRadius`

Comment: thank you, i am gonna read it. How about the second question? I have made two Views, and the View which is under, should have borderRadius like in the pic.. Could you give me some hint about how to do it Sir?

Comment: @helloWorld Updated answer and you have to make sure that gradient area is large enough to have some area under bottom section so when you apply radius so it visible otherwise you won't notice border radius.

Comment: but i just have different two Views, one is like blue, other one is white.
So when blue finishes, white starts. How can i blue one go a bit under? should i give height then?

Comment: May be you can give white section marginTop in negative if both section are without height property.

Comment: that was what i looked for. Thank you. Btw is there anyway to get in touch with you when i have questions with react native, react, javascript?  or would it be okay if i just sent you link of the question over here?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way and a hard way:

Hard Way:
Use `radial-gradient` CSS property, here's an example: [is it possible to do a curved line with css gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494235/is-it-possible-to-do-a-curved-line-with-css-gradient)

Easy Way:
Get an Image designed with the same background and set as `background-image`