# Curved linear-gradient background?

Tags: css, gradient

please excuse my horrible paint drawing but I don't really know how else to describe what I am looking for. I currently have a box with a background that is utilizing a linear-gradient

```
`linear-gradient(330deg, white 30%, grey 45%, white 0)`
```

It looks similar to the terrible illustration. However, my project needs a slight curve, which obviously the linear gradient cannot supply. Is there anyway to change that linear gradient such that there is a slight curve down the diagonal line?

What I have: [linear-gradient through box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9nVs.png)

What I need: [curve through box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNNTB.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Michael _ You may find this answer useful >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494235/is-it-possible-to-do-a-curved-line-with-css-gradient

Comment: Do you want each of the colors to have a curve or only the top one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it this you want to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Document</title>
<style>
  div {
    background-image: radial-gradient(
      ellipse farthest-side at 92% 378%,
      #9fa4a9 21%,
      #7b7b7b 100%,
      #3e3f40 35%
    );
    width: 421px;
    height: 150px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<style></style>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This was a massive help. I was able to make some edits to your radial-gradient to get it just right. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelHowell of course you can adjust it as per your need

Answer (score -1):

try using `radial-gradient` instead of `linear-gradient`. if you play a little bit with it you may achieve what you want

Learn more about `radial-gradient`:

- [CSS Radial Gradients (W3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients_radial.asp)
- [radial-gradient **reference** (W3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_radial-gradient.asp)
- [radial-gradient (MDN Web Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient())